# This row query working properly please help to change it eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel

```
SELECT `foduu_listing`.`id`,`foduu_listing_filedetail`.`primary`, `foduu_listing`.`name`,`foduu_listing`.`filemanager_id`,`foduu_filemanager`.`filepath`,`foduu_detail_orders`.`listing_id`, COUNT(`foduu_detail_orders`.`listing_id`) AS count,SUM(`foduu_detail_orders`.`total`) AS total 
FROM foduu_listing
 left join `foduu_detail_orders` on `foduu_listing`.`id` = `foduu_detail_orders`.`listing_id`
 left join `foduu_listing_filedetail` on `foduu_listing`.`id` = `foduu_listing_filedetail`.`listing_id`
 left join `foduu_filemanager` on `foduu_listing`.`filemanager_id` = `foduu_filemanager`.`id` 
where `foduu_detail_orders`.`listing_id` = 593
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to your question and what kind of error you get

Comment: You could either do something like what @namelivia has suggested or add respective models to each table, define relations and use eloquent to fetch in more cleaner way

Comment: This raw query working properly but i am not  converting this query to eloquent query, so please help to change it eloquent query

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```php
DB::table('foduu_listing')->select('foduu_listing.id`,foduu_listing_filedetail.primary, foduu_listing.name,foduu_listing.filemanager_id,foduu_filemanager.filepath,foduu_detail_orders.listing_id')
    ->leftJoin('foduu_detail_orders', 'foduu_listing.id', '=', 'foduu_detail_orders.listing_id')
    ->leftJoin('foduu_listing_filedetail', 'foduu_listing.id', '=', 'foduu_listing_filedetail.listing_id')
    ->leftJoin('foduu_filemanager', 'foduu_listing.filemanager_id', '=', 'foduu_filemanager.id')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(`foduu_detail_orders`.`listing_id`) AS count')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(`foduu_detail_orders`.`total`) AS total')
    ->where('foduu_detail_orders.listing_id', 593)
    ->get();
```

If instead of calling get at the end you call `toSql` you can check the query generated:

```sql
select `foduu_listing`.`id``,foduu_listing_filedetail`.`primary, foduu_listing`.`name,foduu_listing`.`filemanager_id,foduu_filemanager`.`filepath,foduu_detail_orders`.`listing_id`, COUNT(`foduu_detail_orders`.`listing_id`) AS count, SUM(`foduu_detail_orders`.`total`) AS total from `foduu_listing` left join `foduu_detail_orders` on `foduu_listing`.`id` = `foduu_detail_orders`.`listing_id` left join `foduu_listing_filedetail` on `foduu_listing`.`id` = `foduu_listing_filedetail`.`listing_id` left join `foduu_filemanager` on `foduu_listing`.`filemanager_id` = `foduu_filemanager`.`id` where `foduu_detail_orders`.`listing_id` = ?
```

However you are not making use of Laravel tools if you just translate your queries from raw SQL to Eloquent like this, you should define your models and your relationships properly and then make use of that for querying your data.

Comment: You are welcome, please consider voting and making the issue as resolved.